# Make IDE treat all variables with same name of particular type

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, ide, phpdoc

I am using the following code in NetBeans PHP IDE.

> /* @var $DB Database */

The problem is everytime I use `$DB` I had to include this line for auto complete to work. Is it possible to create a universal line so as to avoid adding it everytime?

Answer (score 0):

Is $DB a global variable?  If so, and you have your include_path configured in your IDE's project so that it knows where $DB originates, then autocomplete would work for it.